# Highcharts : click event not detected after a redraw

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and I want to trigger some events when the user clicks on the labels of the chart. It works fine as long as I do not redraw.
When I use `chart.redraw()` the click event is no longer triggered
Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/AJeantet/28oebumb/3/

Does anyone know a workaround ?
Thanks,
Adrien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current issue is that you're attaching event handlers to DOM nodes that are destroyed when the chart is redrawn.

Change

```
$('.label_wrapper').click(function() {
  console.log('Still working...');
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('click','.label_wrapper', function() {
  console.log('Still working...');
});
```

The handlers will be attached to the document instead of the nodes that are being redrawn, meaning that the event handler will never be destroyed.

See the [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/BaobabCoder/28oebumb/7/).

Comment: This doesn't fix his issue.

Comment: it does. Take a look at the fiddle

Comment: I did. Click the Jan label, and it logs. Click redraw, and then click Jan again; it doesn't log. How would closing a button tag possibly fix the issue from a logical standpoint?

Comment: Yes you are wright. I misunderstood the error. I updated my answer

Comment: I like your solution way better than mine. Nice!

Comment: Thank you for the review

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay